# is it possible to create a hyperlink in excel from the cell text?

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink

like the title says, i want to see if its even possible to create a hyperlink with a pre-defined string of a url but the page be whatever the text in the sell is. example:

say the A1 cell has TEST TEXT
i would like to say, google it. create a hyperlink like it is below but the text of A1 be replaced in the A1 part of the url...
https://www.google.com/search?q=(A1)
-to-
https://www.google.com/search?q=TEST TEXT

im not familiar with excel so please be kind lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have a space in a query string. A space needs to be replaced with either the `%20` or a `+` sign. The correct URL would be, for e.g.

`https://www.google.com/search?q=TEST+TEXT`

You can build that in Excel with the formula

```
=HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/search?q="&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","+"),"Search Google for "&A1)
```

Comment: THANKS! that works! the only problem i seem to have is that i have to create a new column, say B1, with like GOOGLE so it creates the link. i simply drag it down to automatically create it down the column. i would have liked the actual column A1 text had the link but this will work. its just for my own cataloging. thanks again!